# On props (store) change Do

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

I have a store Object (React-Redux App using connect to interact with my JAVA API) called parameters.

this object is updated in another component when I update inputs tick boxes ect...

In my new Component I have a "Save as Template" button which sends this Object after some processing as a Json to my API.

I'd like to now CATCH changes to this Object (parameters) within my new component with any odd function.

So that I may run a series of "if" tests on it, see if some inputs are missing and hide or grey out the "Save as template" button correspondingly.

Is that possible?

```
componentDidMount() {

}
```

and

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {

}
```

don't seem to be of much help.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: From the sound of it you can do this all from the `render()` function.

Comment: You can validate the object in your render method and render the button as diabled if the validation fails. No need to use lifecycle methods for this.

Comment: @Aaron true dat

Comment: @trixn yes well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea this is a pattern I've had to use a few times, and I used lodash.isEqual to handle it.

```
import { isEqual as _isEqual } from "lodash"
```

Say you have a parameters object in you store and you're watching it in your component in mapStateToProps for example (or however else you're getting access to it):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    parameters: state.someApp.parameters,
});
```

You can then check if anything has changed in your componentWillReceiveProps:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(!_isEqual(this.props.parameters, nextProps.parameters)) {
      this.props.sendSomeRequestWithParameters(nextProps.parameters)
    }
}
```

Comment: that's pretty cool thanks. alternitively as it turns out in this case I can simply declare two booleans (I actually have two parameter objects) between my render and return and store within them the answer to my "if" test batteries. Once within the render at my Button I can decide which of two sets of buttons I decide to display based on if (booleanOne || booleanTWO). see what I mean?